# Matching strings in for loop in Python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, arcpy

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks like this

[image]

```
df = {'Regions': {0: 'REGION1', 1: 'REGION2'}, 'x': {0: '1249-43,1269-12,1280-12', 1: '1267-12,1269-12,1280-12'}}
```

and a list of raster files called `rasters`

```
rasters = 'SI_1206-33_50cm.tif', 'SI_1249-43_50cm.tif', 'SI_1269-12_50cm.tif', 'SI_1267-12_50cm.tif', 'SI_3865-17_50cm.tif'
```

What I'd like to do is to create a new list of all entries in `rasters` that  match the strings in `df.x` per region.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    region = row['Regions']
    tiffs = row['x']
    rasterlist = []
    for raster in rasters:
        if raster in tiffs:
            rasterlist = rasterlist.append(raster)
            print(rasterlist)
```

As a result when iterating over rasters, I am attempting to get for the first iteration a `rasterlist` containing `'SI_1249-43_50cm.tif'` and `'SI_1269-12_50cm.tif'` for REGION1 and for the second iteration a `rasterlist` containing only `'SI_1267-12_50cm.tif'` for REGION2. The list `rasterlist` I would like to use as input for further processing using the `MosaicToNewRaster_management` fucntion in `arcpy`.

What does not seem to work with this code is the pattern matching, I get an empty `rasterlist` variable for each iteration. I assume this is the case because the different list items in df.x are separated by a comma and the `in` function does not seem to work. This is where I am stuck and hoping to get some input.

Comment: Can you provide the output of this or specify what about this doesn't work for you?

Comment: @NickChapman I just edited the question and tried to explain (hopefully clear enough?) what does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking in the wrong direction. You are using

```
if raster in tiffs
```

but `tiffs` is just something like `'1249-43,1269-12,1280-12'` which obviously none of the rasters are in. You need to split apart the list of tiffs and check in the reverse direction to see if any of the tiffs are in the rasters.

```
tiffs = row['x'].split(',')
raster_list = []
for raster in rasters:
    for tiff in tiffs:
        if tiff in raster:
            raster_list.append(raster)
            # Assuming each tiff matches with only one raster
            # you can break to save some time here.
            break
print(raster_list)
```

If you could tell us more about the mapping between the rasters and tiffs then there's probably something more efficient that can be done using `dict`s or `set`s.